# What is the most efficient way to emulate sum types on Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Suppose you had two structs,

```
struct Weapon {
    int atk;
    int duration;
}
struct Armor {
    int def;
    int duration;
}
```

then, how do you write this:

```
struct Equipment {
    /* can be either an Weapon or an Armor */
}
function atkOrDef(Equipment equip) returns(int) {
    /* returns the atk if an Weapon, or the def if an Armor */
}
```

If that isn't possible, how would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Solidity does have inheritance. You could define a class **Equipment** that is extended by classes **Weapon** and **Armor** (you have to define them separately. Then add an attribute that uniquely distinguishes from Weapon and Equipment (an integer with a predefined value). Then you could use this attribute in the **atkOrDef** (call a getter method of the attribute) and use it to determine if **Equipment equip** is either **Weapon** or **Armor**.

Something along the lines of:

```
contract Equipment {
    uint atk;
    uint duration;
    // Define an attribute that uniquely distinguishes Weapon from
    // Armor
    uint unique;

    function Equipment(uint atk_param, uint duration_param) {
       atk = atk_param;
       duration = duration_param;
    }

    // getter method for the attribute
    function getWeaponOrArmor() constant public (uint) {
       return unique;
    }
}

contract Weapon is Equipment {

    // This is the constructor of Weapon
    function Weapon(uint atk, uint duration) public {
        unique = 0;
    }

}
```

Define **Armor** similarly:

contract Armor is Equipment {

```
// This is the constructor of Weapon
function Armor(uint atk, uint duration) public {
    unique = 1;
}
```

}

Next, in the **atkOrDef** function check the attribute against the respective values:

```
function atkOrDef(Equipment equip) returns(int) {
    if(equip.getWeaponOrArmor()) return 0;
    else 1;
}
```